# How to write a bpy.app.handlers handler thats only called once?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I have a problem with app handlers in Blender and Python. I am trying to write a script that can start a render and automatically upload it when it finished.

So far it works, but now I want to see the render process as well.

I tried `bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`, but that doesn't wait until the render is finished until executing the next parts of the code, where the upload happens.

After a bit of search I stumbled across app handlers, which seem to be what I need.
So I tried this:

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene):
    print("render complete")

bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(my_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(my_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Blender's *Text Editor*, it works fine at first. But when I try it a second and third time, it starts printing "render complete" multiple times at once in the console. Each time I run it, it prints one time more.
So I guess something is wrong here, and if the simple printing doesn't work, I rather don't try to use this app handler to upload the render result ;)

Anyone has an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you're adding the render handler multiple times.

If you want a one-off handler, you can do this:

```
def my_handler(scene):
    print("render complete")
    bpy.app.handlers.render_post.remove(my_handler)
```

... you'll also want to change unregister not to error when the handler has run.

```
def unregister():
    if my_handler in bpy.app.handlers.render_post:
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(my_handler)
```

---

Note: if you end up writing many one-off handlers, you might want to investigate writing a decorator, so a new handler could look like:

```
@call_once(bpy.app.handlers.render_post)
def my_handler(scene):
      print("render complete")
```

... where `call_once` can handle details to avoid a lot of repetition.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as OP. I need a way of holding a 'for' loop until the render is over. I can't find a way of doing so, and blender crashes.